# Nested IF and AND Statement for a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a cell, U5 which has a value between 2-18 ...

If U5 < 6, assign a 1
If U5 is >5 but <9, assign a 3
If V5 is >8 but <15, assign a 6
If V5 is >14, assign a 9

Trying to do this with a nested IF statement that I believe will require "AND" clauses.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1412500/edit) to show us the formula you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do this:

with nested `IF`s:

```
=IF(F3<6,1,IF(F3<9,3,IF(F3<15,6,9)))
```

(No need for `AND`s)

Or using `INDEX/MATCH`:

```
=INDEX({1,3,6,9},MATCH(F3,{0,6,9,15},1))
```

Comment: Very good, but the returned values are not [1,2,3,4], but [1,3,6,9]. This is easy with your nested `IF()`, but not with `MATCH()` unless you add another table.

Comment: @AFH - you,re right, I got distracted and just used 1,2,3,4 instead of  1,3,6,9. See edit to my answer

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!  That was extremely helpful!